# For bigquery.routines.create, which access to grant?

Tags: google-bigquery

In order for user to have bigquery.routines.create ability, which access do I grant to user on BigQuery?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grant user with bigquery.routines.create permission, you can use `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` or `roles/bigquery.dataOwner`.

Both of them allows you to use `bigquery.routines.*` permission. You can read more about it in [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_predefined_roles).

I hope it helps.